# Can an iframe be made responsive using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm stuck in a situation where the HTML designer says that your iFrame cannot be responsive using Bootstrap, but after a research I came up with the following links where it says iFrame can be made responsive: [link1](https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/bootstrap/forums/responsive-youtube-iframe-within-bootstrap-expandcollapse/) and [link2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/O4H28d1-d7Q).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#dpa" data-toggle="tab">DPA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#rn" data-toggle="tab">Antwon</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
              <p>test</p>            
            </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="dpa" data-src="http://www.drugpolicy.org/">
              <iframe src=""></iframe>
            </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="rn" data-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/37138051?badge=0">
              <iframe src="" width="500" height="203" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/37138051">ANTWON ♦ HELICOPTER</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/tauszik">Brandon Tauszik</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#myTabs').bind('show', function(e) {  
    paneID = $(e.target).attr('href');
    src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');
    // if the iframe hasn't already been loaded once
      if($(paneID+" iframe").attr("src")=="")
      {
        $(paneID+" iframe").attr("src",src);
      }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/YbT7r/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can iframe be made responsive using Bootstrap?

Comment: An iframe can be made to be 100% of the parent using CSS. Bootstrap is CSS.

Comment: The contents of an iframe, if they are from another domain, cannot be changed to be responsive.

Comment: Thanx Christina, what if i have 2 iframe's and the src is dynamically set, so can they be made responsive in Bootstrap?

Comment: The iframe itself can be made responsive with css, you can use the responsive embeds for videos as in the answer by Jake, you can create css to make the iframe respond in your media queries. You cannot make the contents of an iframe responsive if it's coming from a location that you don't control the css.

Comment: What if the contents loaded inside the iframe are static, like for e.g a kinda registration form or any other static form? Will the iframe control the content and make it responsive if we design the css accordingly using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can using bootstrap !

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

## [REFERENCE LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)

Comment: Thanx Jake, what if i have 2 iframes and both the iframe src is set dynamically, so will the iframe be responsive? Basically the content within the iframe will be kinda static form, so will it still be responsive?

Comment: Anything can be loaded within the iframe, it will provide responsive

Comment: The only condition is iframes should be designed like above based on your requirements

Comment: Kool, thanx a lot Jake.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I have a Youtube video embedded in an iframe that scales responsively whether the browser window is resized horizontally or vertically.  [You can see it in action here (link)](https://www.thebouqs.com/en/content/8-how-it-works).  I'm sure you could probably alter this to suit your needs:

```
function resizeHeroVideo() {
    var content = $('#hero');
    var contentH = viewportSize.getHeight();
    contentH -= 158;
    if ($(".navbar-fixed-top")[0]) {
        contentH -= 30;
    }
    content.css('height',contentH);

    if(player != null) {
        var iframe = $('.videoWrapper iframe');
        var iframeH = contentH - 150;
        if (isMobile) {
            iframeH = 163; 
        }
        iframe.css('height',iframeH);
        var iframeW = iframeH/9 * 16;
        iframe.css('width',iframeW);
    }
}
```

The complete code for that page is also on [gist](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/647fcdda17cd23715872).